# Difference between client and driver program in Database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, reactive-programming, r2dbc

**Context**

I am looking for postgres jdbc drivers which supports reactive programming. I came across https://r2dbc.io/ which is a spec for reactive api's for jdbc.There are two sections in the site
one is "Clients" and another is "Drivers"

The client section starts with

> R2DBC encourages libraries to provide a “humane” API in the form of a client library. R2DBC avoids implementing user-space features in each driver, and leaves these for specific clients to implement.

Postrgres implementation of r2dbc - https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql starts with

> This implementation is not intended to be used directly, but rather to be used as the backing implementation for a humane client library to delegate to

**My Questions**

1. What is the difference between client and driver in general, or at-least in above context ?
2. What is the "humane api" being referred here ?

Comment: The client is the guy who calls the humane API that calls the driver.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thanks for the reply. In normal jdbc scenario, I just use one driver jar, but there are two(client and driver) here, why ? One thing striking to me now is, in normal scenario, java.sql.* package is client(interfaces part of this package is 'humane' API) and vendor specific jdbc jars are drivers(implementations). Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: You have an extra JAR for the R2DBC interfaces. This corresponds to the JDBC API which is built into the JRE so no extra JAR.

Answer (score 1):

An example of **client** and **human api** in Spring is the `DatabaseClient` in Spring 5.3.

The original R2dbc spec defines the APIs using reactive streams spec. But `DatabaseClient` is based on the project reactor, which provides richer APIs for developers.

Compare my example [connection factories](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/connection-factories)(I have to use Reactor APIs to wrap the R2dbc APIs to make it more easy for use) and [database clients](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/database-client).